# "Move feature" for points, manually moving a set of points with the mouse in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, point

For moving a feature, the process is to edit the layer, use the "move feature" button, then drag and drop the feature.

I have a point shapefile layer, and would like to move a set of points. This video does exactly what I need to do at this timestamp: https://youtu.be/yiihopTnewg?t=50

However, in my case, there is no "Move feature" button. I can use the "Edit vertex" button, but I can only move one point at a time, and have to select in a different manner to the normal yellow selection process.

In the image below, I want to move the selected features to align with the square.

[image: Screenshot showing the absence of the Move feature button]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to enable Advanced Digitizing Tools from the Toolbar menu. `Right click the main toolbar -> Toolbars -> and enable Advanced Digitizing Tools`. The Move feature is located inside this menu:

[image]

Here is the tool:

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thanks! It is also possible with the Vertex editing tool, but a bit clunky as it doesn't use the selected features, you have to reselect with that tool first. This will be an easier method.

Comment: @gisol You are welcome. Glad it worked :).